# How to solve kartik\dialog\Dialog not found in yii2?

Tags: yii2

I can run controller in development correctly but I facing error `kartik\dialog\Dialog not found` in production

like thise picture

[image]

Why this thing happen?

How I can check it? in Vendor folder maybe.

and How to solve it?

Here is my `composer.json`

```
{
    "name": "vendor/myweb",
    "description": "Description of project myweb.",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Administrator",
            "email": "developer1@myweb.com"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "kartik-v/yii2-dialog": "*"
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check in vendor folder that vendor/kartik-v/yii2-dialog folder is present or not.

Comment: @Chinmay it's present, I just copy and paste from other vendor folder. but error remain exists

Answer (score 1):

1. Check in `vendor` for this, if it does not exist, go to point 2.
2. Add this line to require section in project-directory/composer.json file

> "kartik-v/yii2-dialog": "*"

Then run in project directory command:

```
composer update
```

Comment: it's present, I just copy and paste from other vendor folder. but error remain exists

Comment: You can't just copy & paste folder with kartik plugin. Use `composer update` in project directory OR (you never should do this!!!!!!) open file `/vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php` and add proper lines to autoload this plugin...

Comment: using `composer update` make my vendor corrupt `Class yii\debug\Module does not exist`. any other solution? question updated.

Comment: What do you mean corrupt? What happens? Btw, other solution is in my previous answer.

Comment: my web show `Class yii\debug\Module does not exist`

Comment: How about adding `"yiisoft/yii2": "~2.0.8",` to composer.json? Propably u dont have yii in vendor...

Comment: I just solved with copy and paste vendor from other backup, and it works. anyway is "yiisoft/yii2": "~2.0.8" doesn't remove current web application? I worried if it delete my app.

Comment: No, it adds all Yii2 components to vendor. Please, do it in proper way, as i said, u cant just copy & paste vendor or vendor components. If something is missing or not working - fix it, dont go around.

Comment: Yes you can paste the entire folder from one project to another and it should keep working. The best way is using Composer, but if you copy the entire directory it should work too. Checked.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you found the answer by now !
IF NOT:
I have struggled with this problem long enough to feel desperate :)
here's what I ended up doing:
1- install Dialog using composer : composer.phar require kartik-v/yii2-export "*
if it gives these errores :

```
Problem 1
- kartik-v/yii2-dialog dev-master requires bower-asset/bootstrap3-dialog ~1.34 -> no matching package found.

- kartik-v/yii2-dialog v1.0.1 requires bower-asset/bootstrap3-dialog ~1.34 -> no matching package found.

- kartik-v/yii2-dialog v1.0.0 requires bower-asset/bootstrap3-dialog ~1.34 -> no matching package found.

- kartik-v/yii2-dialog 1.0.x-dev requires bower-asset/bootstrap3-dialog ~1.34 -> no matching package found.

- Installation request for kartik-v/yii2-dialog @dev -> satisfiable by kartik-v/yii2-dialog[dev-master, 1.0.x-dev, v1.0.0, v1.0.1].
```

You need to run this command: `composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:^1.2.0"`
it rebuild dependencies and set jquery libraries to match with the ones required by Kartik Dialog. Good luck